# 12 volt relay shorting out?

Tags: relay

I've got a vehicle that has a small bed with a dumping action controlled by an electric actuator. With the ignition on, power to the switch, you press up and the bed rises, you press down it goes down. When you let go of the switch, nothing happens, as it is designed. There is one relay to raise the bed and one relay to lower it. The vehicle is powered by two 12 volt car type batteries wired in parallel.

Here's what happened:

The batteries were dead so we jumped it using a 24 volt system designed to jump start 24 volt vehicles. We hooked up to the positive terminal on one battery and the negative on the other battery. We turned the ignition to the on position, trying to start the vehicle but it wouldn't start. We raised the bed to get at the engine, since it was hooked to the jumper we could raise it.

We left the vehicle charging for a few minutes, 10-15 minutes. When we came back, the bed was down and the actuator had torn itself apart but the motor of the actuator was still spinning, while no one was pressing the switch. We accidentally left the ignition switch in the "on" position but even after turning the ignition off, the actuator motor kept spinning.

My question is, is it possible that charging a 12 volt system with a 24 volt system shorted out the 1080p relay, making the connection on its own?

I know using the 24 volt jumper wasn't the healthiest idea but could it have sent enough current to the relay to arc it into turning it on?

I apologize for the simpleton terms but alas, I am no electrician so I am seeking advice from experts.

Comment: Isn't 1080p an HD video standard?

Comment: If you're seeking advice from experts, please make your question _clear and readable_. This is basically just one block of letters, and the experts here has to read a lot of questions. Chances are no one cares about this.

Comment: Use <Enter> x 2 for a paragraph. Note that repair questions are off-topic unless substantial troubleshooting has generated a good electrical engineering question.

Comment: [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) is calling you.

Comment: Fix the Great Wall of Text.  Remember that you are asking volunteers for a favor.  Disrespecting those you seek a favor from is not smart.

Comment: I'm guessing 1080p was also the part number of the relay.

Comment: even things can suffer death by electrocution, as you have found out. .... it is quite possible that you have killed the entire electrical system of your truck

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible that charging a 12 volt system with a 24 volt system [does something strange]?

Stop and actually *think* about it.  You are really asking *"If I abuse something, could it then possibly no longer function as specified?"*  Seriously!?

You said yourself that the two 12 V car batteries in your system are wired in parallel.  They therefore together act as a big 12 V battery.  You tried to apply 24 V to two 12 V car batteries.  If this 24 V charger was able to supply sufficient current, then those batteries are now junk.  You are lucky that the resulting gasses didn't explode.

Whatever electronics is connected to these 12 V batteries probably wasn't designed to handle 24 V for very long.  It could also be dead now.  In fact, that sounds like what happened.  The over-voltage caused something to blow, which permanently turned on one of the relays.

Your mention of a "1080p" makes no sense whatsoever in the context of a dump bed going up and down.  Without further definition (note that you didn't supply *any*), "1080p" means "1080 scan lines, progressive".  That's common for HDTV, for example.  1080 is the number of scan lines on the screen, and "progressive" means all are drawn each refresh period.  In this case, "progressive" is the opposite of "interlaced".

Next time, pay attention to the voltage and other ratings.  Or, get someone who knows what they are doing.  Connecting 24 V to a 12 V system is just plain dumb.

Comment: "Bazinga"  he said.